# How to sum up amount in django choices

Tags: django, model

I'm trying to find the total amount of material costs in columns given I have to select the amount with django choices.

I have tried adding using `self.amount1+ self.amount2` to no avail.

```
PO_STEEL_COST_CHOICES = (
    ('10000' ,'10000'),
    ('20000','20000'),
    ('30000','30000'),
    ('40000','40000'),
    )

PO_ELECTRICAL_MATERIAL_CHOICES = (
    ('10000' ,'10000'),
    ('20000','20000'),
    ('30000','30000'),
    ('40000','40000'),
    )

PO_SUBCONTRACTORS_CHOICES = (
    ('10000' ,'10000'),
    ('20000','20000'),
    ('30000','30000'),
    ('40000','40000'),
    )

class ProcurementTeam(models.Model):
    project_name = models.OneToOneField(Project, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    po_steel = models.FileField(upload_to='files/ProcurementTeam/posteel/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    po_steel_cost = models.CharField(max_length=120,choices=PO_STEEL_COST_CHOICES, default='None', blank=True)
    po_electrical_materials = models.FileField(upload_to='files/ProcurementTeam/poelectrical/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    po_electrical_materials_cost =models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=PO_ELECTRICAL_MATERIAL_CHOICES, default='None', blank=True)
    po_subcontractors = models.FileField(upload_to='files/ProcurementTeam/posubcontractor/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    po_subcontractors_cost = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=PO_SUBCONTRACTORS_CHOICES, default='None', blank=True)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)

    def total_material_cost(self):
        """Function to return total procurement PO cost"""
        total_procurpo = self.po_steel_cost + self.po_electrical_materials_cost + self.po_subcontractors_cost
        return total_procurpo
```

I expect the output to be 40,000 given that I have chosen 10000, 20000 and 10000 but the current output is 100002000010000.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

since the options are given as a `string` within `quotes('')` thus they are getting `appended` instead of getting `added`

```
total_procurpo = int(self.po_steel_cost) + int(self.po_electrical_materials_cost) +int(self.po_subcontractors_cost)
```

Comment: Thank you... It has worked. Another way I've found is using float instead of Int.

Comment: Using stings and casting them to float will subject you to rounding issues. If these amounts are money, I'd strongly urge you to use a DecimalField.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with `sum` and `map`:

```
total_procurpo = sum(
    map(
        float,
        (
            self.po_steel_cost,
            self.po_electrical_materials_cost,
            self.po_subcontractors_cost,
        ),
    )
)
```